# Liquibase not dropping sequences on Postgres

Tags: postgresql, maven, sequence, liquibase

i'm driving crazy already as liquibase (on postgres) is not dropping sequences when running a liquibase:dropAll through the maven plugin. These sequences are created by liquibase itself through different changelogs.
I've found that there was the same issue once for Derby but that is resolved already.

Is anyone aware of this issue or/and a workaround for that? I could check for its existance on the changelogs and drop if necessary but that's not the point :P

thanks !

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of this problem but do you have logs or exceptions that you could add to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, At the "3.3.2" version and the dropALL just droping the tables, the sequences, functions, triggers and other objects continuos there.

The documentation say:
Resolved on version 3.3.3
http://blog.liquibase.org/
[CORE-1768] – Oracle dropAll fails on spatial tables and sequences

I'll test now.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've ended up doing a fast config as a "temporary" workaround that runs a custom SQL after a dropAll doing the rest of the job for liquibase :S

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in Liquibase. If you already have changelogs, etc. that demonstrate the problem, submit them to the [Liquibase Jira Bug tracker](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:issues-panel)